# magento google analytics don't work

Tags: magento, google-analytics

I followed the procedure of inserting google analytics to my magento website.

1. Signed in my Google analytics account and got my : TrackingID : UA-.....
2. In Magento: Configuration -> Sales -> google API -> google analytics : enable=yes, account number=UA-......

nevertheless I see in google analytics : *Tracking not installed* and on the magento pages not a sign of the tracking code.

in my ftp I see: /app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/googleanalytics.xml that contains:

```
<reference name="after_body_start">
    <block type="googleanalytics/ga" name="google_analytics" as="google_analytics" /> 
</reference>
```

Whats wrong?

Comment: I mostly find that if something I'm expected to appear doesn't, then some form of cache needs flushing.

Comment: HTML blocks need to be flushed, then you should see the code in the after body begin block when the cache rebuilds.